# Vue SVG loader is not loading accurately

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs3

I am having problem using svg loader. I tried to load file but it is giving me this error in console

> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:21 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to
> execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided
> ('/assets/twitter-brands.6620c8ae.svg') is not a valid name.
> at createElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:290:19)
> at mountElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3910:29)
> at processElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3898:13)
> at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3818:21)
> at mountChildren (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4008:13)
> at mountElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3917:17)
> at processElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3898:13)
> at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3818:21)
> at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4357:21)
> at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:195:29)
> createElement @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:21 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3771 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3750 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3670 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3869 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3778 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3750 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3670 componentUpdateFn @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4218 run @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160 setupRenderEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4337 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4120 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4078 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3673 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3869 processFragment @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4037 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3666 componentUpdateFn @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4218 run @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160 setupRenderEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4337 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4120 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4078 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3673 render @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4822 mount @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3157 app.mount @
> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:1572 eval @ main.js?56d7:11
> ./src/main.js @ app.js:1277
> **webpack_require** @ app.js:849 fn @ app.js:151 1 @ app.js:1350
> **webpack_require** @ app.js:849 checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46 (anonymous) @ app.js:925 (anonymous) @ app.js:928 Show 5 more frames

Here is the screenshot of code. Serve is compiling it correctly and not giving any error. Path is absolute correct.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
<template>
  <header>
    <nav class="container">
      <div class="branding">
        <router-link class="header" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
          >Fireblogs</router-link
        >
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link">
        <ul>
          <router-link class="link" to="#">Home</router-link>
          <router-link class="link" to="#">Blogs</router-link>
          <router-link class="link" to="#">Create Post</router-link>
          <router-link class="link" to="#">Login/Register</router-link>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <menuIcon />
  </header>
</template>

<script>
import menuIcon from "../assets/Icons/twitter-brands.svg";
export default {
  name: "Navigation",
  components: {
    menuIcon,
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is the package.json code

```
{
  "name": "vue-with-firebase",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.1.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-firebase": "^1.0.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.3",
    "vuefire": "^2.2.5",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add ```vue-svg-loader``` to your webpack config?

Comment: I added in vue.config.js file

Comment: https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

After long research, I have solved the error. I wasn't using the same versions of vue and vue template compiler. I fixed that by reinstalling them

Reinstalling vue

```
npm i vue@latest --save
npm i vue-template-compiler@latest --save
npm i vue-server-renderer@latest --save
```

After these I also reinstalled other dependencies using `@latest`